# Using Symfony Forms for JSON API and dynamic multidimensional array

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I use the Symfony Form Component for our RESTish JSON API (inspired by http://williamdurand.fr/2012/08/02/rest-apis-with-symfony2-the-right-way/).

Now I have some multidimensional POST-Request with always the same root-keys (`name` and `actions`) but different subelements.

```
{
    "name": "Name",
    "actions": [{
        "type": "type_of_action",
        "config": {
            "name": "name",
            "assigned_to": "23cb1a6b-5a99-4b91-ae72-b52882b45f47",
            "information": "Lorem Impsum"
        }
    },{
        "type": "type_of_other_action",
        "config": {
            "name": "name",
            "dueDate": "2016-12-01"
            "active": "true"
        }
    }]
}
```

As you can see, `config` can be different on every `actions`-element. I need something like this:

```
->add('config', [TaskActionType::class, OtherActionType::class])
```

I know, it would not be possible to render such a form, but I need it only to validate the request and transfer it into an reliable array (`$data = $form->get('actions')->getData()`).

Answer (score 0):

Try to send option param into form and then render that sub form type.

Controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(MainForm::class, null, [
           'method' => Request::METHOD_POST,
           'param' => $param
       ]);
```

MainForm:

```
/**
* {@inheritdoc}
*/
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
     $param = $options['param'];


    if (param == "type1") {
        $builder
            ->add('config', FormType1::class))

    } elseif (param == "type2") {
        $builder
            ->add('config', FormType2::class))
    }

}
```

I hope is that what you need.

Comment: Sorry, not really. One request can include *both* `config` objects.